# Node.js hangs when trying to connect to mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm installing an app for the third time on a new machine **OS Sierra** and having a hard time getting node to communicate with mongo. I haven't had this issue before. I've got the latest stable version of node/express/mongoose and I installed mongo fine via homebrew. When I run this, it just hangs and does nothing - creating a connection to the database in the mongod terminal, and refreshing causes it to throw an already connected error, so it is indeed working in some capacity. I even tried swapping out the URI to a heroku mLab instance and still the same behavior:

```
app.get('/api/mongotest', function(req, res){

  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/local', function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.json(err);
      } else {
        res.json('Success!');
      }

  });

});
```

Comment: Also, node and mongo seem to be opening a lot of PID processes all at the same time

Comment: You are connecting to the database every single time the endpoint is called. You should connect once during the server start.

Comment: agreed - i'm just running a test to see if I can get it to ever get to a success or show me a darn error that I can do something with!

Comment: Did you try to add some console.log or to use debug in the connect callback? Check what the error is without trying to pass it to the response. Just print it in the console first.

Answer (score 1):

FIX: I came across this issue when trying the ScotchIO (express, node, mongo) tutorial and then *again* with the Traversy Media youtube one. Turns out there's something weird with the version of mongoose i was using, if you downgrade to  `"mongoose": "4.7.6"`in your pkg json, delete node modules and run `npm install` you're golden.

Hope this helped someone...

Credit to this chap for solving it: https://github.com/gfzabarino

Answer (score -2):

Aha - it looks like my node version was not compatible with mongo! Thanks!

Comment: The Thanks and Comments on Answer are supposed to be comments of particular answer not the new answer.